# У меня крашит тг бот на Python

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot("1066480766:AAHyKj-BmQFjvjdpDL9M2GQrC57cHhwRg2o")
mass = 0

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hi! Capacity of storage = 100. /fill - fill storage on 10. /capacity - show capacity")
    while True:
        @bot.message_handler(commands=['fill'])
        def earn_command(message):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "You fill storage on 10")
            mass += 10
        @bot.message_handler(commands=['capacity'])
        def balance_command(message):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Capacity : " + str(mass))
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

здесь после ввода /fill выполняется вывод , но потом в консоли вот такая ошибка :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack.py", line 16, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "C:\Users\Yurii\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 496, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Yurii\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 555, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\Yurii\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 518, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\Yurii\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 117, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\Yurii\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 69, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "stack.py", line 12, in earn_command
    mass += 10
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mass' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас вообще странный код. Зачем вы определяете функции внутри бесконечного цикла? А ошибка у вас потому, что читать глобальную переменную внутри функций можно без дополнительных телодвижений, а вот менять глобальную переменную можно только если прямо указать в начале функции, что она глобальная:

```
global mass
```

Comment: Спасибо , убрал функции из цыкла , написал global mass и всё равно ошибка та же

Comment: @YuraFrolyak Где написали? Надо в той функции, где у вас `mass += 10` это написать перед её использованием